# jQuery hover drop down menu not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML:**

```
<div style="position:relative" id="user">User
    <div id="logout" style="display:none; position:absolute; right:0px; top:20px">Logout</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("#user").hover(function(){
    $('#logout').toggle();
});
```

The logout div appears when hovering over the word User, the problem is, when moving the mouse into the logout section it disappears.

Comment: jquery accepts two functions

Comment: It works for me: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ooqd151n/).

Comment: Create a fiddle to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Not working for me, I actually posted stripped down code, here is the full: http://jsfiddle.net/k03qgy37/

Comment: I have kind of sorted it, I had a couple of things in line at the top of the page using either display:inline or float:left, which didn;t like if the mouse went below this 'line', making the heights of all those divs bigger meant the mouse would stay in the line and it works, except for the bottom of the div which I can live with

Answer (score 1):

As your 'logout' text becomes visible it is *outside* of `#user` so as you move the cursor over to `#logout` you are leaving the hover-area.

The following [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkm0xbgw/) should help explain. In it `#logout2` remains *inside* the hover area.

```
<div style="position:relative" id="user">User
    <div id="logout" style="display:none; position:absolute; right:0px; top:20px">Logout</div>
</div>
<hr />
<div style="position:relative" id="user2">User2
    <div id="logout2" style="display:none; position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px">Logout2</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qkm0xbgw/

<strike>(P.S The inline css in your example mark-up is incorrect and is missing colons between some properties)</strike>

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve this with a simple CSS rule instead of jquery:

```
#user:hover #logout {
    display: block !important;
}
```

(The `!important` is needed because otherwise it will not overwrite your inline style)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
id = $(this).attr('id');
if(id != "logout"){
    $('#logout').toggle();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is bound to happen as the `hover` method checks for cursor entry and exit into the selected element (here `#user`). So as soon as the cursor exits the div the `toggle` method is triggered again. As seen in jQ docs:

> The .hover() method, when passed a single function, will execute that handler for both mouseenter and mouseleave events. This allows the user to use jQuery's various toggle methods within the handler or to respond differently within the handler depending on the event.type.

You can try using mouseenter and  mouseleave :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#outer").mouseenter(function() {
            $("#inner li").css("display","block");
        });
        $("#inner li").mouseleave(function() {
            $("#inner li").css("display","none");
        })
    })
```

With html like :

```
<ul id = "outer"> 
<li>Link1
    <ul id = "inner" style = "position:relative;">
        <li style = "display:none;">Sublink1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```